# Extract tabular data from a html and save as text file

Tags: html, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, urllib2

I wanted to extract the tabular data from `html` and save as `text file`

```
import urllib2, numpy as np, pandas as pd
fo = 'fo.txt'
url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
rows = pd.read_html(html)
print type(rows)
print rows

for row in rows:
    this_row = "|".join([str(td) for td in row])
    fo.write(this_row + "\n")
```

But got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    fo.write(this_row + "\n")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

the resulted tabular data in the text file would look as in the original link:
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/

Any help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write to a text file you need a file object. In your source code the `fo` object is a `string`.

In python you can open a file for writing like this:

```
with open(fo,'w') as text_file:
    for row in rows:
        this_row = row
        text_file.write(this_row + "\n")
```

Comment: thanks. it helped partially, still the problem is:  it is writing only header (first row of table)

Comment: @jean open the file before you start to iterate in your loop. I edited the answer to include a loop. And check your identations.